# Disable automatic calculation excel from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have my sheet coded to disable automatic calculation when it opens and it works but with a caveat. If no other sheets are open it works fine, but if another sheet is open prior to opening it, it inherits the behaviors of the other sheet and ignores the `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual` code.

Is there anyway to force excel to override the settings of the other sheet so that my sheet can open into manual calculation mode?

Comment: Do you need to trade data between the two sheets when you open the other one?  i.e.: Are you copy/pasting, or referencing the two sheets between each other in any way?

Comment: I do not think you are right. This setting is on application level. There is no inheritance unless you have some code which prevents your code `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual` from running.

Comment: @Storax is correct, but there's ways around this.  You could instantiate the Excel application with those settings prior to opening the other sheet.  Or, just open a new instantiation altogether (if you don't need to trade/share data between the two workbooks/sheets).

Comment: The issue is I have to close all excel windows for this to work. Otherwise when I start up the sheet, and the former sheet is open with calculations set to automatic, it inherits that setting.